# GUI of app built in FinalBuilder(with dcc32.exe) differs from one built in Embarcadero IDE

Tags: delphi-xe2, finalbuilder

When I build an app in FinalBuilder, apparently with dcc32.exe, GUI looks like windows xp app, but if I compile it in IDE, it looks normal as Windows 7 program. Also TLinkLabel is recognized as a simple TLabel. Any ideas what can be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to enable runtime themes during the compilation of XE2 project in FinalBuilder, you have to include manifest file in resources:

> default_app.manifest

[image]